# OpenCV: drawKeypoints() in Python vs. Julia

Tags: python, julia

I'm rewriting this OpenCV program in Julia:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('simple.jpg',0)

# Initiate STAR detector
orb = cv2.ORB()

# find the keypoints with ORB
kp = orb.detect(img,None)

# compute the descriptors with ORB
kp, des = orb.compute(img, kp)

# draw only keypoints location,not size and orientation
img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img,kp,color=(0,255,0), flags=0)
plt.imshow(img2),plt.show()
```

How do I convert this line in Python

```
img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, kp, color=(0,255,0), flags=0)
```

to Julia format?

Comment: Please include a MWE.
That can be copies and pasted directly into a python interpreter and run.
Including the Import statements.
Without that kinda thing, we are left to guess what you are talking about.
Eg is cv2 an opencv binding? Who knows.

Comment: Yeah is cv2 a class in Python (will need to become a type in Julia), or an existing library import, etc. Not enough info to help here.

Comment: Sorry guys, hopefully my edit will help

Comment: Have you read the docs on the OpenCV interface for Julia [here](https://github.com/Daetalus/Julia-OpenCV-binding)?  Also, it's not clear from the code you posted how familiar you are with the concepts of differences between programming languages, packages, etc.  For instance, you're not going to be able to just plunk python code into Julia or directly use python modules in Julia.  You need to understand Julia syntax and how it differs from Python and use that to inform your changes.  Perhaps try some tutorials listed [here](http://julialang.org/learning/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An equivalent line in Julia that works would be:

```
img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, kp, 0, color=(0,255,0), flags=0)
```

The change is in pos3, where you should provide an argument for `outImage`, though the scalar value `0` will do.